# Getting 0.0 for latitude and longitude while showing current location in map

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, geolocation, userlocation

I am using the following code to get my current location. But the problem I am facing is, it always returns 0.0 for latitude and longitude. I have turned on the GPS settings in the phone and set all the permissions. But still I am facing this.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

customLocationListener = new CustomLocationListener();

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(

        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,

        0,

        0,

        customLocationListener);

class CustomLocationListener implements LocationListener{ ............

      public void onLocationChanged(Location argLocation) { 

         if(location != null) {     

        int latitude=(int)(argLocation.getLatitude()*1E6);   

        int longitude=(int)(argLocation.getLongitude()*1E6);


              }
       } ........ }
```

Do any one of you know why?

Note : My activity extends MapActivity not Location Listener

Comment: for emulator..have you send the geo points from Emulator Control ?

Comment: Are you sure you've got GPS fix? The map may use `PASSIVE_PROVIDER` provider to show current location (i.e. may not even be using GPS).

Comment: latitude and longitude should be doubles, not ints Also, what is 1E6 supposed to be?

Comment: are you checking it on or phone...if it is on emulator then you have to send lat-lon manually from ddms as @MayurParekh said.

Comment: @hanry..I am checking in the phone only not in the emulator.

Comment: @inazarul..yeah I have set the GPS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this way

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


        Criteria locationCritera = new Criteria();
        String providerName = locationManager.getBestProvider(locationCritera,
                true);
        if(providerName!=null)
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(providerName);

        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                0, locationListener);
```

in mylocationlistener set your location object

```
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

        if (loc != null) {
            location = loc; 

        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Mayur Parekh...am getting null for location if I do location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(providerName); I got the value for provider as gps.

Comment: I got what the problem was, it was because the place where I sit was not receiving proper GPS connection..!!

I tried in the emulator by hardcoding latitude and longitude, then it works.


Inference: It is better to try in emulator for test to get the current location of user

Comment: Can you tell me, how to get the address of the user location i.e., not the coordinates rather the full address where he is currently staying

Comment: you should post this as a new question. anyways you can use the GeoCoder class 
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault()); 
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);

Comment: Hi Erum, the code in accepted answer works fine. You can follow that.Make sure you are outside the building, sometimes if you check inside the building it may not work !!

Answer (score 7):

also check this is one of the reason.
Go to maps default application and allow user to allow latitude and longitude option .In our application When the GPS signal blinks and when it stops we will get the latitude and longitude. This Worked for me

---

### Edit 1

1. Open Google Maps app and click button on map to get current location.
2. When you allow Google map permission, then only other apps permission will work. ***(and I feel this is big bug)***
3. Now go to your app and try to get current location and it will work.

*This is ugly, but we have follow those steps to get current location in our app.*

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you want..!

```
public void getCurrentLocation() {
        LocationManager locationManager;
        String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(context);
        Criteria crta = new Criteria();
        crta.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        crta.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        crta.setBearingRequired(false);
        crta.setCostAllowed(true);
        crta.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(crta, true);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0,
                new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                            Bundle extras) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        if (location != null) {
                            double lat = location.getLatitude();
                            double lng = location.getLongitude();
                            if (lat != 0.0 && lng != 0.0) {
                                System.out.println("WE GOT THE LOCATION");
                                System.out.println(lat);
                                System.out.println(lng);                                                         
                            }
                        }

                    }

                });
    }
```

Comment: @Noby... I tried, but am getting 0.0 in the line double lat = location.getLatitude(); So still my problem continued.

Comment: turn your gps off then try...! Make sure you given enough time to get your location details.(wait for five minutes).

Answer (score 1):

**CustomLocationManager.Java**

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

public class CustomLocationManager {

    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private LocationValue locationValue;
    private Location networkLocation = null;
    private Location gpsLocation = null;

    private Timer mTimer;

    private boolean isGpsEnabled = false;
    private boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    private static CustomLocationManager _instance;

    private CustomLocationManager() {}

    public static CustomLocationManager getCustomLocationManager() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new CustomLocationManager();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public LocationManager getLocationManager(Context context) {
        if (mLocationManager == null)
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return mLocationManager;
    }

    public boolean getCurrentLocation(Context context, LocationValue result) {
        locationValue = result;
        if (mLocationManager == null)
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        try {
            isGpsEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {}

        try {
            isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {}

        if (!isGpsEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
            return false;

        if (isGpsEnabled)
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, gpsLocationListener);

        if (isNetworkEnabled)
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, networkLocationListener);

        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.schedule(new GetLastKnownLocation(), 20000);

        return true;
    }

    LocationListener gpsLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mTimer.cancel();
            locationValue.getCurrentLocation(location);
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(networkLocationListener);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    private LocationListener networkLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mTimer.cancel();
            locationValue.getCurrentLocation(location);
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(gpsLocationListener);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    private class GetLastKnownLocation extends TimerTask {
        CurrentLocationHandler handler;

        GetLastKnownLocation() {
            handler = new CurrentLocationHandler();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(gpsLocationListener);
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(networkLocationListener);

            if (isGpsEnabled)
                gpsLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            if (isNetworkEnabled)
                networkLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }

    private class CurrentLocationHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public final void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (gpsLocation != null && networkLocation != null) {

                if (gpsLocation.getTime() > networkLocation.getTime())
                    locationValue.getCurrentLocation(gpsLocation);
                else
                    locationValue.getCurrentLocation(networkLocation);

                return;
            }

            if (gpsLocation != null) {
                locationValue.getCurrentLocation(gpsLocation);
                return;
            }

            if (networkLocation != null) {
                locationValue.getCurrentLocation(networkLocation);
                return;
            }

            locationValue.getCurrentLocation(null);
        }
    }
}
```

**LocationValue.Java**

```
import android.location.Location;

public abstract class LocationValue {
    public abstract void getCurrentLocation(Location location);
}
```

**YourActivity.Java**

```
private void getCurrentLocation() {
        CustomLocationManager.getCustomLocationManager().getCurrentLocation(this, locationValue);
    }

    public LocationValue locationValue = new LocationValue() {
        @Override
        public void getCurrentLocation(Location location) {
            // You will get location here if the GPS is enabled
            if(location != null) {
                Log.d("LOCATION", location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Here, when we give a permission  for location then after just wait for few seconds,GPS will take time for stable location ,after that we will get the actual values of lat and long.

Comment: Working perfect... Good Solution

Answer (score 0):

Here, when we give a permission  for location then after just wait for few seconds,GPS will take time for stable location ,after that we will get the actual values of lat and long.

Setting -> GPS Enable

[Reason for lat long value comes 0.0](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-SimpleLocation/issues/1)