# I am sometimes getting longitude and latitude of 0,0

Tags: android, geolocation

Most of the time it out puts my actuall coordinates but sometimes it I get 0,0
can someone please explain why?

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);

Location location = null;
for (int i = 0; i < providers.size(); i++) {
    if ((location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(providers
            .get(i))) != null) {
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: I bet there's a spot in the Atlantic, just south of Ghana, that has *loads* of geotagged photos and Foursquare checkins.

Comment: You never do anything with the coordinates.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644063/getting-0-0-for-latitude-and-longitude-while-showing-current-location-in-map)? Sounds like they saw something similar.

Comment: I do it later and then I send them to a DB