# Android getting Longitude and latitude always returns 0.0

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the longitude and latitude for android, here is my code:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
            this_activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);




 public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        longitude = Double.toString(loc.getLongitude());
        latitude = Double.toString(loc.getLatitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

Manifest Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I'm always getting 0.0s for longitude and latitude

Comment: have you added permissions in the Manifest?

Comment: yes I added this: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: are you testing on Emulator or a real device?

Comment: real Device ASUS KOOS with android 4.3

Comment: check out this soultion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644063/getting-0-0-for-latitude-and-longitude-while-showing-current-location-in-map

Comment: Hi, Hassene. I tried your code, it worked fine for me for first time and then from second time onwards its returning me lat 0.0 and long 0.0. Even if the in Settings, the location permission is on. Can you please help me figure out the issue.

Answer (score 5):

except the permissions that @AshishPedhadiya mentioned you are listening only to the GPS provider.

```
LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);
```

GPS does not work inside. So when you test your application it will practically always return the (0,0) location. You may want to listen to NETWORK_PROVIDER as well which in absent of the GPS location it estimates the location coming from cell towers and WiFi spots.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);
```

Furthermore to get a quick geographic location check out the `Application.getLastKnownLocation()` method.

Comment: it works with NETWORK_PROVIDER but I need internet connection and this doesn't use the GPS, I still have empty values if I don't connect to WIFI

Answer (score 2):

```
<!-- Needed only if your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher. -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

You need to add permission request in the manifest file above 5.0 version as mentioned in Android developer portal

[Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestPerformance)

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
add this permission to your manifest file
```