# Why does the latitude and longitude showing 0 value inside my application?

Tags: android

I'm creating a GPS tracker application in android. 
Now I've written some basic code that pinpoints users location(latitude + longitude) on his/her android screen.

The problem is, when everything is said and done, it's showing a value 0.0. for both latitude and longitude.

Why is it happening?

Below is the code...

MainActivity.java file

```
package vidyabusapplication.android.com.vidyabusapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.test.mock.MockPackageManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;  
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button Btn_trackLocation;

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 2;
    String mPermission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;

    GPSTracker gps;
    TextView location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();

        try {

            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, mPermission) != MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {mPermission}, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);
            }

        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        Btn_trackLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
                if(gps.canYouGetLocation()) {
                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                    location.setText(latitude+" "+longitude);
                }
                else {
                    gps.enableGpsViaSettingsOptionAlert();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void init() {
        location = findViewById(R.id.trackLocationText);
        Btn_trackLocation = findViewById(R.id.startTrackingButton);
    }
}
```

GPSTracker.java file

```
Package vidyabusapplication.android.com.vidyabusapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

/**
 * Created by mental on 27/2/18.
 */

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetWorkEnabled = false;
    boolean canYouGetLocation = false;
    Location location;
    double latitude, longitude;
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 60000;

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {

            locationManager = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            isNetWorkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if(!isGPSEnabled && !isNetWorkEnabled) {

            }
            else {
                this.canYouGetLocation = true;

                if (isNetWorkEnabled) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return null;
                     }

                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }

                    if (isGPSEnabled) {

                        if (location == null) {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        }
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if(locationManager != null) {
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }

            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        if(location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        if(location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        return longitude;
    }

    public boolean canYouGetLocation() {
        return this.canYouGetLocation;
    }

    public void enableGpsViaSettingsOptionAlert() {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        dialog.setTitle("GPS DISABLED!");
        dialog.setMessage("Want to enable it now?");

        dialog.setPositiveButton("Enable", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
            }
        });

        dialog.setNegativeButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="vidyabusapplication.android.com.vidyabusapplication.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trackLocationText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Track Location"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/startTrackingButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Start"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It is to be taken in account that I've all the permissions for location pinpointing inside my androidManifest.xml file.

Comment: please post error log.

Comment: there isn't any error at all. The apk builds successfully. Only it shows 0 value for latitude and longitude

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting 0.0 for latitude and longitude while showing current location in map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644063/getting-0-0-for-latitude-and-longitude-while-showing-current-location-in-map)

Comment: what duplicate? Have you even read the above code?

Comment: are you building it on an emulator ? if so you would need to set the coordinates first